# "unable to find valid certification path to requested target" in Fabric 2.2.2 network with Fabric Gateway Java

Tags: ssl, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca, certificate-store, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-java

I am trying to use Fabric Gateway Java to access a Fabric 2.2.2 network. I have imported the peer crt and also the ca.crt in the peer directory into the JDK cacerts keystore but I am getting PKIX path building failed:

```
    org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.exception.ProposalException: getConfigBlock for channel iprd failed with peer peer0.  Status FAILURE, details: Channel Channel{id: 1, name: iprd} Sending proposal with transaction: bcd0ce03de31ea26b5b3c01b366c51c8cc29f66655c41bbe9ae4ddee8a669ed8 to Peer{ id: 2, name: peer0, channelName: iprd, url: grpcs://peer0.iprd-net:7051, mspid: msp} failed because of: gRPC failure=Status{code=UNAVAILABLE, description=io exception
                            Channel Pipeline: [SslHandler#0, ProtocolNegotiators$ClientTlsHandler#0, WriteBufferingAndExceptionHandler#0, DefaultChannelPipeline$TailContext#0], cause=javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General OpenSslEngine problem
[...]
                            Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
[...]
                        Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

is there a way to diagnose what is the missing certificate that the JDK is looking for (or any other way to find the problem?). thanks